# wordpress ajax relationship query

Tags: sql, wordpress

Using the relationship field from Advanced Custom Fields I link artists to events. Both these artist and events are custom post types. For each event, the post IDs of the related artists are stored in an array as a custom meta field (lineup_artists).

On each event page I list all the artists. When you click on an artist, I'd like to show all the events where you can find this artist (through an AJAX call which shows the results in a bootstrap modal). I've tested the AJAX call and it's working, but there's something wrong with the query (takes very long to complete).

In my function I have:

```
$ArtistID = $_POST['ArtistID']; // Gets the ArtistID from the AJAX call

$meta_query = array(
    'key'       => 'lineup_artists',
    'value'     => '"' . $ArtistID .'"',
    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
);

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'events',
        'meta_query'        => array($meta_query),
        'posts_per_page'    => 5,
        'post_status'       => 'publish',   
);
```

If I dump the results of wp_query, I get the following sql query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS yt_posts.ID FROM yt_posts 

INNER JOIN yt_postmeta ON (yt_posts.ID = yt_postmeta.post_id)

WHERE 1=1 

AND yt_posts.post_type = 'events' 
AND (yt_posts.post_status = 'publish') 

AND ( (yt_postmeta.meta_key = 'lineup_artists' AND CAST(yt_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%\"17497\"%') ) 

GROUP BY yt_posts.ID ORDER BY yt_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

When I paste this query in phpmyadmin it takes very long to complete (I've never seen it finish because it takes so long).

Is this because the artist IDs are stored as an array? Someone told me that this is not very efficient and that these relations should be stored in a separate table (which I don't know how to do). Is there something wrong with my query or is this a very inefficient way of querying relations?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a usage question of a third-party software, here namely Wordpress.

Comment: There are lots of questions about Wordpress and in particular about wp_query around here right? I'll post the question on wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There are a lot of questions as well about colors or the weather in the sky - even on this website. That's not important, question is if it is a programming question or not. Better look on Wordpress Answers and and please leave a link here to your question so this can be more easily streamlined.

Comment: Seemed to me like it is a programming question since it's about optimisation of an SQL query. But anyway, the question escalated into a more WP related question so you're right :-). See the post on WP Answers [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110591/wordpress-ajax-relationship-query)

Comment: We will also get better answers there because on that website are the wordpress pros :)